# How to do before or after pseudo-element be aligned like common blocks

Tags: html, css

I need some text be added inside a pseudo-element, but aligned (justified in my case) like common block.

Example:

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.block:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "Text2";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">Text1</div>
  <div class="block block3">Text3</div>
</div>
```

'Text2' is now near 'Text3'. I need 'Text2' to be in the middle.

Comment: set `margin:50 50;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea is to make the element positioned relatively to the container and you can easily align it:

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
  position:relative;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.block:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "Text2";
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">Text1</div>

  <div class="block block3">Text3</div>
</div>
```

Or make it a pseudo element of the main container and use flexbox to change the order and align it:

```css
.container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display:flex;
}

.block3 {
  order:2;
}

.container:after {
  content: "Text2";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">Text1</div>

  <div class="block block3">Text3</div>
</div>
```

Here is another idea using float:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.block1 {
  float: left;
}

.block3 {
  float: right;
}

.container:before {
  content: "Text2";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">Text1</div>

  <div class="block block3">Text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But realy they all limeted by two bloks.

Answer (score 3):

Text2 is "near" Text3 because it's inside of Text3 - that's how pseudo-elements work.

What you did with `.block:not(:first-child):before` is basically equivalent to:

```
<div class="block block3">
  <div>Text2</div>
  Text3
</div>
```

A clean way to accomplish what you want with no positioning tricks would be using flexbox with the `order` property like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container:after {
  content: "Text2";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.block3 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">Text1</div>
  <div class="block block3">Text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @РоманКоптев Is this a class assignment or something? Why is it not permitted?

Comment: I can't use flexbox. It's a desision of my chief. I think for browser compatibility. Any way. Ican't change this

Comment: @РоманКоптев I see. You should let your chief know flexbox has 97.32% global compatibility according to CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox - in comparison, `::before` has around 97.64%: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to apply borders, backgrounds etc. to the text (so you are OK with `display:inline` instead of `inline-block`), you can also do the following:

```css
.container {
  text-align: justify;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: inline; /* not inline-block — so both real and generated text is aligned as one */
  font-size: 20px;
}

.block:not(:first-child):before {
  content: "Text2 "; /* white space is crucial, text-align:justify works by stretching it! */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block1">Text1</div>
  <div class="block block3">Text3</div>
</div>
```